# Python&PyGTK: Stop while on button click

Tags: python, button, click, while-loop, pygtk

I'm working on programming some application and I would like to create while loop when button is clicked and if it's clicked again to stop it. This is the code for button:

```
self.btnThisOne = gtk.Button("This one")
self.btnThisOne.connect("clicked", self.startLoop)
```

The code for startLoop def would be:

```
def startLoop(self):
    while self.btnThisOne?(is_clicked)?:
        #do something
```

How to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot just have an unconstrained while loop running in the main thread of your application. That would block the main [gtk event loop](http://www.gtk.org/api/2.6/glib/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html) and you won't be able to process any more events. What you probably want to do is spawn a thread.

Have you considered using a [`ToggleButton`](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk/2.24/GtkToggleButton.html) instead of [`GtkButton`](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk/2.24/GtkButton.html)? The closest thing to an `is_clicked` method is `is_active` and you'll find that in toggle buttons.

Here's an example of starting and controlling a thread depending on the state of a toggle button (replace `triggered` with `clicked` and `ToggleButton` with `Button` if you want a regular button):

```
import gtk, gobject, threading, time

gobject.threads_init()

window = gtk.Window()
button = gtk.ToggleButton('Start Thread')

class T(threading.Thread):
    pause = threading.Event()
    stop = False

    def start(self, *args):
        super(T, self).start()

    def run(self):
        while not self.stop:
            self.pause.wait()
            gobject.idle_add(self.rungui)
            time.sleep(0.1)

    def rungui(self):
        pass # all gui interaction should happen here

thread = T()
def toggle_thread(*args):
    if not thread.is_alive():
        thread.start()
        thread.pause.set()
        button.set_label('Pause Thread')
        return

    if thread.pause.is_set():
        thread.pause.clear()
        button.set_label('Resume Thread')
    else:
        thread.pause.set()
        button.set_label('Pause Thread')

button.connect('toggled', toggle_thread, None)

window.add(button)
button.show()
window.show()
gtk.main()
```

This PyGTK [FAQ answer](http://faq.pygtk.org/index.py?req=show&file=faq20.006.htp) might prove helpful. Cheers.

Comment: Can I put functions for start threading into existing class? How to create only Start and Stop functions without pause?

Comment: To stop the thread, simply `thread.stop = True`. Keep in mind that once a thread terminates it cannot be started again (you'll have to create a new one).

Comment: I would like to start threading from different class&method, but I doesn't work - http://pastebin.com/xmHqK6Qc . Is it possible to send data to T.run() method or to create method inside class Start to start threading with method in this class?

Comment: Okay, now I achieved out how to start threading from method from different class. It is possible to transport some data to toggle_thread and apply it to T.run and T.rungui?

Comment: Yes. Use a thread safe data structure like a [Queue](http://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html) and share it between the main-thread and the new thread.

Comment: I don't understand this Queue -.-" Could you please edit your current code with example of Queue? Is it possible to start threading from method not toggle button?